# Why is this not thread safe?

Tags: java, multithreading, unix

I have a multithreaded application on Linux. I deduce the calling user's id by parsing the /net/proc/tcp file. Basically OS adds the local/remote addr and port info in a system file, and we try to match it with the http socket details.

```
 private String identifyCaller(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest) {
        IdService idService = new IdService();
        OptionalInt uid = idService.getUID(
                httpServletRequest.getLocalAddr(),
                httpServletRequest.getLocalPort(),
                httpServletRequest.getRemoteAddr(),
                httpServletRequest.getRemotePort());
       ...
```

and the IdService class goes like

```
class IdService {

    private static Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\s*\\d+: ([0-9A-Fa-f]+):([0-9A-Fa-f]+) ([0-9A-Fa-f]+):([0-9A-Fa-f]+) ([0-9A-Fa-f]{2}) [0-9A-Fa-f]+:[0-9A-Fa-f]+ [0-9A-Fa-f]+:[0-9A-Fa-f]+ [0-9A-Fa-f]+\\s+([0-9]+).+");

    private final String ipV4Path;
    private final String ipV6Path;

    public IdService() {
        this.ipV4Path = Constants.PROC_NET_TCP_PATH;
        this.ipV6Path = Constants.PROC_NET_TCP6_PATH;
    }


    public OptionalInt getUID(String localAddr, int localPort, String remoteAddr, int remotePort) {

        OptionalInt uid;
        try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(ipV4Path))) {
            String line;
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                uid = getUID(line, localPort, remotePort, remoteAddr); 

                if (uid.isPresent()) {
                    return uid;
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            log.error("Exception reading {} file. ", ipV4Path, e);
            // Handle
        }

private OptionalInt getUID(String line, String remoteAddr, int reqLocalPort, int reqRemotePort) {
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(line);
        if (!matcher.matches()) {
            return OptionalInt.empty();
        }
        int count = matcher.groupCount();
        ... 
        // More rules and if match then returns a matched field 
   }

}
```

I see that unless I use a new instance of IdSevice the scanning for UID returns empty Optional (there is no match for the current socket). The contents in "/net/proc/tcp" change but I am wondering what causes this to be thread unsafe. All the work seem to happen with local thread variables so I was previously using a singleton object but that gave wrong results. The members variables are constant String object and the only static is a final member. So what causes this to be thread unsafe?

Comment: You use this one file for all concurrent calls? What guarantees that a thread doesn't see the details of another concurrent call?

Comment: Yes, this is a Linux provided feature where _ALL_ TCP socket processes (local/remote addr/port are listed). There is no guarantee on what thread will read. All that we need is to find the mapping that the current thread is trying to find.

Comment: In that case all I can think of is that your thread checks the file, before the OS has written the entry for your socket process. (but that's just a guess)

Comment: The other thing I can think is that the socket times out before the thread reads it (so the OS removes the entry). But is there anything unsafe about  BufferedReader?

Comment: Your BufferedReader is not shared among threads, so that's totally thread safe.